# How to generate an array of objects in Alpine.data with Livewire Eloquent collection and Adding properties in those js objects

Tags: arrays, object, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

and thanks for your attention and help,

I have a Collection in my livewire controller. This collection contains a list of players, with some properties : here we will just focus on id and name.
So we can imagine that we have 3 players in the collection :

```
Players[0] : 'id'=>1, 'name'=>'Yann';
Players[1] : 'id'=>2, 'name'=>'Robert';
Players[2] : 'id'=>3, 'name'=>'Jessica';
```

I need to get these players in my alpine data.
I can easily get these players in Alpine with the @js method :

```
window.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
        Alpine.data('data', () => ({
            players: @js($players),
        }))
    })
```

So, now I have in my alpine.data :

```
players: [
               { id: 1, name: 'Yann' },
               { id: 2, name: 'Robert' },
               { id: 3, name: 'Jessica' },
    ]
```

Now I can easily display the players in my html with a template x-for :

```
<template x-for="player in players">
    <p x-text="player.name"></p>
</template>
```

But I want to add some additionnal properties in each player object. Those properties will be updated in front depending user's actions.
I would like to get something like this :

```
players: [
              { id: 1, name: 'Yann', touched20: 0, touched15: 0 },
              { id: 2, name: 'Robert', touched20: 0, touched15: 0 },
              { id: 3, name: 'Jessica', touched20: 0, touched15: 0 },
   ]
```

All additionnal properties are the same for each object in the array, so I imagine i could use a foreach loop to put them in the objects.
But I can't see and don't understand  how i can include a loop in my alpine.data script to do this.

Anyone could help me  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit my question because I found a solution :

I just make a loopPlayers function outside of my alpine data and call this function in the alpine data :

```
function loopPlayers() {
            let players = [];
            const livewirePlayers = @js($players);
            livewirePlayers.forEach(element => {
                players.push(element);
            });

            players.forEach(function(element) {
                element.touched15 = 0;
                
            })
            return players;
        }
```

And in alpine.data :

```
players: loopPlayers(),
```

Now I have my collection of players from my livewire controller & I have new properties for each element of the collection in the js data

That was easy, as usual I guess :)